# Vertical Bar Graph Generator

Tags: python, graph

I have created a python program that prints a vertical bar graph made from fields and values inputted by the user. It works by first creating a horizontal bar graph and then going through each layer and determining whether to print a letter, a `"|"`, a `"_"`, or a space. I would appreciate any feedback on the program and things I could do to improve it.

```
import re

feilds = input("Input| ex: dogs,10 cats,23 birds,67\n").strip()
while not re.match("^(\w+,\d+ ?)+$", feilds):
  feilds = input("invalid input, use this format:\nfeild,value feild,value feild,value...\n").strip()
width = int(input("How wide is your output window in characters? "))
scale = float(input("Scale: "))
vals = dict([feild.split(",") for feild in feilds.split(" ")])
for k, v in vals.items():
  vals[k] = int(v)
spacing = int(width / len(vals.keys()))
horizontal = ["-" * int(v * scale) + "|" + k[::-1] for k, v in vals.items()]
vertical = []
for x in reversed(range(len(max(horizontal, key=len)))):
  layer = []
  for val in horizontal:
    try:
      if val[x] == "-":
        layer.append("|")
      elif val[x] == "|":
        layer.append("_")
      else:
        layer.append(val[x])
    except IndexError:
      layer.append(" ")
  vertical.append(layer)
print("\n")
print("\n".join((" " * (spacing - 1)).join(layer) for layer in vertical))
```

ex:

input:

```
dogs,20 cats,18 fish,25 birds,10
80
.5
```

output:

```
                                        f                    
                                        i                    
d                                       s                    
o                   c                   h                    
g                   a                   _                    
s                   t                   |                    
_                   s                   |                   b
|                   _                   |                   i
|                   |                   |                   r
|                   |                   |                   d
|                   |                   |                   s
|                   |                   |                   _
|                   |                   |                   |
|                   |                   |                   |
|                   |                   |                   |
|                   |                   |                   |
|                   |                   |                   |
```

**NOTE**: output might be messed up if the width is off by a lot. Make sure to input a width close to what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`feilds` is spelled `fields`. IDEs like PyCharm will identify spelling mistakes in variables.

Why is there a `?` after the space in your regex? Currently I believe it will pass input looking like

```
key,1key,2key,3
```

So you have to fix that edge case, probably by adding a final key-value pair with no space, and making the space in the first group mandatory.

This:

```
vals = dict([feild.split(",") for feild in feilds.split(" ")])
for k, v in vals.items():
    vals[k] = int(v)
```

should be

```
vals = {k: int(v)
        for field in fields.split(' ')
        for k, v in field.split(',')}
```

i.e. don't construct a list in memory only to throw it away.

This:

```
spacing = int(width / len(vals.keys()))
```

can be

```
spacing = width // len(vals)
```

This:

```
for x in reversed(range(len(max(horizontal, key=len)))):
```

doesn't actually need an index at all, since you don't use it. Also, lumping everything into one line is confusing. Instead:

```
longest_horz = max(len(h) for h in horz)
for v in val[longest_horz-1::-1]:
```

Then use `v` instead of `val[x]`.